# Bug Display whith chrome

Tags: django, google-chrome, nginx, bootstrap-4

I am currently on a python / Django project, I am also using bootstrap.

I have a display bug only with google chrome. When I load my page everything is fine then when I scroll, the bug occurs:

[image]

When I reload the page everything is back to normal:

[image]

This bug is not present on the project locally, only from production on a server (ubuntu with Gunicorn and Nginx). When I hover the mouse over this white block, the text displays randomly. This is not the only place where it happens. I don't know if this problem is known but I have absolutely no idea what it might be.

here is the part of the code that we see in picture :

```
<!-- Description content -->      
                <div class="container-fluid main-color-dark-bg pb-4">
                    <div lass="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 col-12 mx-auto mb-3">
                            <a href="{% url 'watch' 'theoretical' level video_previous %}" class="text-left subpart-link">< Précèdent</a>
                            <a href="{% url 'watch' 'theoretical' level video_next %}" class="subpart-link float-right">Suivant ></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Description -->
                    <div class="row col-lg-8 col-md-10 col-12 mx-auto">
                        <div class="">
                            <p class="theoretical-watch-p ext-md-left text-center">
                                {{ video.description }}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Sous parties et Ressources -->
                    <div class="row mx-auto col-lg-8 col-md-10 col-12">
                        <!-- Sous parties-->
                        <div class="col-lg-7 col-12 px-0">
                            <h4 class="theoretical-subpart-title main-color-white text-md-left text-center ">Sous parties</h4>
                            <ul class="list-unstyled text-md-left text-center">
                                {% for s in subparts %}
                                <li class="">
                                    <a href="{{s.subpart_url}}" class="subpart-link">
                                        {{s.subpart_title |title}} 
                                        <span class="subpart-hook">[<span>
                                        {% if s.subpart_time.hour == 0 %}
                                            {{ s.subpart_time|time:"i:s" }}
                                        {% else %}
                                            {{ s.subpart_time|time:"H:i:s" }}
                                        {% endif %}
                                        <span class="subpart-hook">]<span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Ressources -->
                        <div class="col-lg-5 col-12 my-md-0 my-4 text-center mx-auto">
                        <a href="{% url  'watch' 'theoretical' level video.id %}" class="dashboard-cta-watch-button">TÉLÉCHARGER LES RESSOURCES</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End Description content -->
            </div>

            <!-- TAB Menu header mr-lg-auto  mx-md-auto mx-sm-auto mx-auto -->
            <div class="row col-12 px-0 mx-auto">
                <ul class="nav mx-auto d-flex d-inline-flex" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                    <li class="d-inline-flex">
                        <a class="nav-link theoretical-tab-link active" id="tab-memo" data-toggle="tab" href="#content-memo" role="tab" aria-controls="content-memo" aria-selected="true">
                            Les points clés du chapitre
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="header-tab-program" class="d-inline-flex">
                        <a class="nav-link theoretical-tab-link" id="tab-program" data-toggle="tab" href="#content-program" role="tab" aria-controls="content-program" aria-selected="false">
                            Contenu du cours
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="d-inline-flex">
                        <a class="nav-link theoretical-tab-link" id="tab-definitions" data-toggle="tab" href="#content-definitions" role="tab" aria-controls="content-definitions" aria-selected="false">
                            Lexique
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- TAB Menu content -->
            
            <div class="">
                <div class="tab-content w-100" id="myTabContent">
                   
                    <!-- MEMO -->
                    <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="content-memo" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-memo">
                        <!-- Title vidéo et description -->
                        <div class="col-lg-8  col-12 mx-auto mb-5">
                            <!-- Title -->
                            <div class="row px-0 section-title my-auto col-12 mx-auto">
                                <div class="col-12 mx-auto my-auto">
                                    <h1 class="mx-auto section-title text-center">
                                        <hr class="main-color-grey-bg">
                                            <img class="img-left" width="2%" height="auto" src="{% static 'images/pictograms/clover-black.svg' %}"> 
                                            MÉMO
                                            <img class="img-right" width="2%" height="auto" src="{% static 'images/pictograms/heart-red.svg' %}"> 
                                        <hr class="main-color-grey-bg">
                                    </h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                             <!-- APERCU - SECTION LEXIQUE  -->
                            <div class="row mx-0">
                                <!-- colonne contenu -->
                                <div class="col-12">
                                     <ul class="list-unstyled mt-5">
                                     {% for sp in subparts %}
                                     {% if sp.subpart_memo%}
                                        <li class="theoretical-tab-content-p-memo">
                                            <h4 class="">{{ sp.subpart_title |title }}</h4>
                                            <p class="theoretical-tab-content-p-memo">
                                               {{ sp.subpart_memo | safe | linebreaks}}
                                            </p>
                                        </li>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- END MEMO -->
```

I don't use anything in particular in the code. I hope that someone could help me!

Comment: Have you checked the Network tab in Developer Tools? Some frontend library might be loaded in different order in prod than dev and cause this kind of behavior.

Comment: hello, thanks for your help. Indeed I see that the loading is different between the dev and the prod. in prod, js files are loaded (in the right order) before css files (and in the wrong order). Maybe the problem is loading the css files in the wrong order ? In this case, is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Also, I note that when I change the window size everything is displayed correctly. 
I have no specific errors in the console

Comment: J'ai également intégré le viewport <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

Comment: When it behaves correctly in prod does it load them in correct order? If it is the ordering of the css you could write your css so that the order doesn't matter or bundle them using something like django-sass-compiler.

Comment: Apparently it does not come from the css. 
I made a video of a few seconds to have a better view of the problem, at the end I update and everything loads correctly : https://www.loom.com/share/15a3d360116e4bc2868ae01421532dd9

Comment: and on other page (bottom) : https://www.loom.com/share/1986bd33488d4de5baae30428431f8b5

Comment: I also specify that this bug is only on google chrome and tested on several computers

Comment: do you have any idea of this problem ? :/  @JuhoRutila

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Can you publish the site somewhere public so that we could see it ourselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple tests I finally identified the problem and solved.

The display bugs (as a reminder, only on google chrome), as seen in the videos and images came from a line that I had placed in my css file.

in my body I had the line overflow: overlay;

```
body{
   font-family: 'main-font-medium', Fallback, serif;
   font-weight: 0;
   font-style: normal;
   /*overflow: auto;*/
   overflow-x: hidden!important;
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

thanks to you JuhonRutila !

I hope this can help other people.